# Form submit takes too much time with input type file

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a problem while uploading the video file. It takes too long time(7-8 minutes) even i upload only 5 or 6MB video file.I have not yet add the code for upload video. I just submit the form and wait too much time for getting the form values.

On my local system it is working fine. Here is configuration for my php.ini

```
post_max_size         250M
upload_max_filesize   250M
max_file_uploads      20
max_execution_time    0
```

here is the form that i have used

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file"  name="uploadfile" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            print_r($_FIlES);
        }
?>
```

Anyone please guide me why it takes too much time to submit the form with video file. Is the problem in my code or is something wrong with configuration in php.ini or problem with my server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why your action is empty?are you sure it is posting?

Comment: cause i want the target to the same page